# ldd: Library cannot be found

Tags: qt, qnx, ldd

I am running ldd command on libqqnx.so on my target board. This list few certain dependent libraries and then throw error called ldd: Library cannot be found. If I do same on libcpp.so.4 of qnx then it does not show such errors.

My question is, the file libqqnx.so is corrupted or should it be listing some more dependent lib files?

output1:

```
# ldd /opt/qt/plugins/platforms/libqqnx.so:
libqqnx.so => /opt/qt/plugins/platforms/libqqnx.so (0x78000000)
libscreen.so.1 => /proc/boot/libscreen.so.1 (0x78040000)
libpps.so.1 => /opt/qt/lib/libpps.so.1 (0x78031000)
libm.so.2 => /proc/boot/libm.so.2 (0x78060000)
libfreetype.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.1 (0x78090000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /opt/qt/lib/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x780e0000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /opt/qt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x78200000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x78600000)
libGLESv2.so.1 => /usr/lib/graphics/iMX6X/libGLESv2.so.1 (0x78037000)
libEGL.so.1 => /proc/boot/libEGL.so.1 (0x78053000)
libcpp.so.5 => /opt/qt/lib/libcpp.so.5 (0x78140000)
libz.so.2 => /proc/boot/libz.so.2 (0x781a0000)
libslog2.so.1 => /proc/boot/libslog2.so.1 (0x78083000)
libicui18n.so.49 => /opt/qt/lib/libicui18n.so.49 (0x78a00000)
libicuuc.so.49 => /opt/qt/lib/libicuuc.so.49 (0x78b10000)
libicudata.so.49 => /opt/qt/lib/libicudata.so.49 (0x78c00000)
ldd: Library cannot be found

output2:    

# ldd /proc/boot/libcpp.so.4:
libcpp.so.4 => /proc/boot/libcpp.so.4 (0x78000000)

#
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks for me that `ldd` is looking for more libraries but it doesn't find them.

If you know another directory that has other libraries (.so* files) allow qnx to search on it for the missing libraries. You can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

For example: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/qt/some_dir`
 [More info here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide%2Ftopic%2Fenvironment_PATH.html)